# If I know difficulty and thresholds of all items can I build a Rasch model and calculate the ability of new patients

Tags: r, item-response-theory, rasch

I'm trying to "reverse engineer" a statistal model used in this article: [ACTIVLIM : A Rasch-built measure of activity limitations in children and adults with neuromuscular disorders](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S096089660700079X)
In this article a common measure of activity limitations for both children and adults with neuromuscular disorders was developed using the Rasch model.

I have no experience building Rasch models but I was asked to write a computer program were a doctor could fill in a questionnaire and the activity measure is calculated automatically.

Below is a table from the article. The Thresh1 and Thresh2 columns I calculated myself.

The authors came up with 22 questions. 14 questions are asked to all patients (B in the ageGroup column). 4 questions are asked to only children (C) and 4 to only adults (A). Patients were asked if they found the tasks in the label column: Impossible(0), Difficult(1) or Easy(2). Patients can also not answer a question.
I calculated the thresholds (columns Thresh1 and Thresh2) with the help from the following sentence in the article: *For example, being able to easily put on a T-shirt requires a measure of at least 0.03 logits; whereas any patient with a measure below -2.39 would be unable to fully accomplish this activity.* Because the Rasch model is one dimensional I assumed I could now calculate the rest of the thresholds.

```
item  label                             ageGroup   Difficulty    SE  Residual Fit(χ2) df  p-value  Thresh1  Thresh2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 a     Hopping on one foot               C             3.57  0.23      0.06   6.20   4     0.18     2.37     4.79
 b     Carrying a heavy load             A             3.03  0.20     -0.43   1.79   4     0.77     1.83     4.25
 c     Running                           C             2.78  0.21     -0.56   0.52   4     0.97     1.58     4.00
 e     Walking upstairs                  B             1.47  0.13     -1.86  10.11   9     0.34     0.27     2.69
 d     Walking more than 1 KM            A             2.29  0.18     -0.61   4.17   4     0.38     1.09     3.51
 f     Standing for a long time          A             1.30  0.18      0.41   0.72   4     0.95     0.10     2.52
 g     Stepping out of a bath tub        B             1.18  0.14     -0.61   9.01   9     0.44    -0.02     2.40
 h     Walking dowstairs                 B             1.03  0.13     -1.50   3.07   9     0.96    -0.17     2.25
 i     Taking a bath                     B             0.27  0.14     -1.02  10.39   9     0.32    -0.93     1.49
 j     Putting on a backpack             C             0.04  0.21     -0.92   5.12   4     0.28    -1.16     1.26
 k     Dressing one's lower body         B            -0.23  0.14     -1.19   7.74   9     0.56    -1.43     0.99
 l     Walking outdoors on level ground  B            -0.26  0.14     -1.10  10.45   9     0.32    -1.46     0.96
 m     Getting into a car                A            -0.33  0.19     -1.13   5.23   4     0.26    -1.53     0.89
 n     Taking a shower                   B            -0.45  0.15     -1.10  10.84   9     0.29    -1.65     0.77
 o     Wiping one's upper body           B            -0.86  0.15      0.77   8.53   9     0.48    -2.06     0.36
 p     Putting on a T-shirt              B            -1.19  0.16     -0.12   7.10   9     0.63    -2.39     0.03
 q     Hanging a jacket on a hatstand    B            -1.28  0.16     -0.48   3.62   9     0.93    -2.48    -0.06
 r     Sitting on the toilet             B            -1.49  0.16     -1.01  10.97   9     0.28    -2.69    -0.27
 s     Washing one's upper body          B            -1.64  0.17     -0.45  14.59   9     0.10    -2.84    -0.42
 t     Opening a door                    B            -2.73  0.19      0.37  14.22   9     0.11    -3.93    -1.51
 u     Closing a door                    C            -3.16  0.26     -0.54   2.38   4     0.67    -4.36    -1.94
 v     Washing one's face                B            -3.33  0.21      0.54   9.57   9     0.39    -4.53    -2.11
```

Maybe the figure below from the article has some extra information. The top panel shows the distribution of activity measures of 369 patients. The lower middle panel in this figure shows the Ogival relationship that makes it possible to convert the ordinal score into a linear activity measure (score range is from 0 to 44)

[image]

My question is do I have enough information to calculate the activity measure myself? I tried to find functions in R that could do this but they all seem to want the original data from questionairres to build a model.

Comment: What is `Fit` column?

Comment: Sorry I edited the table. It's the Chi-square Fit statistics

Comment: So it seems you have insufficient data. Rasch model has two parameters: ability and difficulty and it estimates probability of "correct" answer. You seem to have only difficulty -- you cannot deduce from the fact that someone answered an easy question what is his/her ability!

Comment: To add a little to what Tim has said, what the authors appear not to have acknowledged in the sentence you quote is that a Rasch model is a probabilistic model. What's more accurate is perhaps that someone with an ability of -2.39 would be _unlikely_ to fully accomplish this ability. A person could have an ability much higher than -2.39 and still fail to fully accomplish the activity. Similarly, someone with an ability lower than -2.39 could still accomplish the activity.

Comment: I added a figure from the article. The lower middle panel shows the relationship that converts the total score of the patient in an activity measure.

Comment: If you had a single doctor's responses then you could sum them to give a total score. Using the lower middle panel you could map the total score onto activity. Anything more sophisticated would likely require the author's original data, or your own sample of responses from multiple doctors. Of course you may want to consider whether the sum score is itself sufficient for your purposes